# how to execute nightmarejs in a while loop

Tags: node.js, scripting, screen-scraping, nightmare

## Problem

I'm trying to scrape images and automate pagination. I'm using the `span` description of the items on the page vs the total items: `1 - 20 of 83,829 results`. I want nightmare to run through this while loop, but it hangs and gives a me a `Javascript heap out of memory` error. Is there a way to have this execute each time rather than push onto a stack, cause I feel like that what its doing.

## Code to Fix

```
function scrapeEach(paginate) {
 // while paginate has next scrapeEach
 while (paginate.next) {
   nightmare
     .wait(4000)
     .realClick('#pageNext .results-next')
     .wait(4000)
     .evaluate(() => {
       return document.body.innerHTML
     })
     .then(result => {
        scrapeImages(result);
        paginate.update();
        paginate.state();
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.error('Search failed:', error);
     });
  }
return nightmare.end()
}
```

Here's the extra code that works with `scrapeEach()`, 
I created this a pagination object to keep track of pages like this:

```
function Paginate(url, pgd) {

  this.url = url;
  this.array = pgd.split(" ");

  this.currentPage = Number(this.array[0]);
  this.totalItems = Number(_.join(_.filter(this.array[4], char => char != ","), ''));
  this.itemsPerPage = Number(this.array[2]);
  this.totalPages = Math.floor(this.totalItems / this.itemsPerPage)
  this.next = true;

  this.update = () => {
   this.currentPage += 1;
   if (this.currentPage >= this.totalPages)
     this.next = false;
   }

  this.state = () => {
    console.log("-------- Pagination ----------")
    console.log("current page: " + this.currentPage);
    console.log("total pages: " + this.totalPages);
    console.log("total items: " + this.totalItems);
    console.log("items per page: " + this.itemsPerPage);
    console.log("has next page: " + this.next);
    console.log("------------------------------\n");
  }
}
```

This scrapes the images off one page

```
// scrapes all image data on one page and updates to db
function scrapeImages(html) {
  xr(html, '#returns > li', [
    {
     img: 'dl.return-art > dd > a > img@src',
     title: 'dl.return-art > dt > a@html',
     created: 'dl.return-art > .created',
     medium: 'dl.return-art > .medium',
     dimensions: 'dl.return-art > .dimensions',
     credit: 'dl.return-art > .credit',
     accession: 'dl.return-art > .accession'
    }
  ])((err, res) => {
   if (err)
     throw err;
   Artwork.addArt(res);
 })
}
```

This function starts the whole process

```
// the onview endpoint
function onView() {
  nightmare.goto(config.NGA.online)
  nightmare
    .wait(3000)
    .evaluate(() => {
       return [document.location.href, document.querySelector('span.results-span').innerHTML]
    })
    .then(([url, pgd]) => scrapeEach(new Paginate(url, pgd)))
  }
```

## Error Message

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawOneByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NumberToString(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::Runtime_NumberToStringSkipCache(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x18caa0a079a7
 8: 0x18caa0f37cbc
 Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. The problem was an async issue the while loop was running asynchronously until it finished and then the nightmare instance would never get run. I updated my solution from automating a click to the next page to computing the next page in the url `&pageNumber=` and passing around data about the page, url, and items on the page with a custom page object for this site. I also added some debugging info to display.

```
function Paginate(url, pgd) {

 this.url = url;
 this.array = pgd.split(" ");

 this.currentPage = Number(this.array[0]);
 this.totalItems = Number(_.join(_.filter(this.array[4], char => char != ","), ''));
 this.itemsPerPage = Number(this.array[2]);
 this.totalPages = Math.floor(this.totalItems / this.itemsPerPage)
 this.next = true;

 this.update = () => {
   let chunks = url.split("&").filter(segment => !segment.includes('Number='));

   this.currentPage += 1;
    if (this.currentPage >= this.totalPages)
      this.next = false;

   this.url = _.join(chunks, "") + '&pageNumber=' + this.currentPage;
 }

 this.state = () => {
   console.log("-------- Pagination ----------")
   console.log("current page: " + this.currentPage);
   console.log("total pages: " + this.totalPages);
   console.log("total items: " + this.totalItems);
   console.log("items per page: " + this.itemsPerPage);
   console.log("has next page: " + this.next);
   console.log("current url: " + this.url);
   console.log("------------------------------\n");
 }

}
```

I used async's `whilst` to use a while loop synchronously and execute nightmare over each iteration.

```
function scrapeEach(paginate) {
  // while paginate has next scrapeEach
  let hasNext = () => paginate.next && paginate.currentPage < 10
  async.whilst(hasNext, next => {

   nightmare
     .goto(paginate.url)
     .wait(4000)
     .evaluate(() => {
        return document.body.innerHTML
     })
     .then(result => {
        scrapeImages(result);
        paginate.update();
        paginate.state();
        next();
     })
     .catch(error => {
        console.error('Search failed:', error);
     });
   }, err => {
    if (err)
      throw err;
    console.log("finished!");
  })
  return nightmare;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Limit the processes running parallel

```
    var limit   = 10;       // concurrent read // this can be increased
    var running = 0; 

    function scrapeEach(paginate) {
     // while paginate has next scrapeEach
     while (paginate.next && running < limit) {
       running++;
       nightmare
         .wait(4000)
         .realClick('#pageNext .results-next')
         .wait(4000)
         .evaluate(() => {
           return document.body.innerHTML
         })
         .then(result => {

            scrapeImages(result , function(){

             paginate.update();
             paginate.state();
             running--;

            });
         })
         .catch(error => {
           console.error('Search failed:', error);
           running--;
         });
      }
    return nightmare.end()
    }


   // scrapes all image data on one page and updates to db
    function scrapeImages(html ,cb) {
      xr(html, '#returns > li', [
        {
         img: 'dl.return-art > dd > a > img@src',
         title: 'dl.return-art > dt > a@html',
         created: 'dl.return-art > .created',
         medium: 'dl.return-art > .medium',
         dimensions: 'dl.return-art > .dimensions',
         credit: 'dl.return-art > .credit',
         accession: 'dl.return-art > .accession'
        }
      ])((err, res) => {
       if (err)
         throw err;
       Artwork.addArt(res);
       cb();
     })
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I would use this, I have a condition that needs to be met in the `while` loop and then it automates a click to the next page if there is a next page.

Comment: the condition that there is a next page if there is then it clicks on the next button

Comment: didn't help, still the same issue.

Comment: try with limit 1 or 2

Comment: i have updated your scrapImages function aswell this might be the cause of the problem

Comment: using the new `cb()` i get a `TypeError: cb is not a function`. I've updated the code to use the URL instead of clicking next and addded some logs. Looks like the `limit=10` does work it stops after 10 but the automation is doing nothing its stuck on the first page and just hangs after that. (same thing for when the limit is set to 1 or 2).

Comment: scrapeImages(html ,cb) you have to define cb in you function parameter aswell